# Do I have to call GoogleApiClient.connect() before signing out from GoogleSignInAPI?

Tags: android, google-signin

Google makes a Note in their [Signing Out Users tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect) saying:

> Note: You must confirm that GoogleApiClient.onConnected has been called before you call signOut.

But both on their [Firebase implementation](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L80-L84) and [old Google implementation](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L59-L64) they do not call `GoogleApiClient.connect()` on their `mGoogleApiClient` instance for `onConnected()` to be called before calling `signOut()`.

So what should I follow? The documentation or the examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. `GoogleApiClient.connect()` has to be called - otherwise we'll get an `IllegalStateException`:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

So this is how you sign out:

```
mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            //SIGN OUT HERE
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {/*ignored*/}
                    });
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {/*ignored*/}
        })
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            /*ignored*/
            }
        })
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API) //IMPORTANT!!!
        .build();

mGoogleClient.connect();
```

So I guess they have this part missing in their example code.